# Reinitialize jquery-mobile after inserting a form into the page

Tags: ajax, dom, jquery-mobile, initialization

I'm inserting a form via ajax dynamically into the page. After inserting it into the dom tree, i would like to reinitialize the jquery mobile to style the form. I had a look into http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html but since the documentation is pretty unhelpful for jquery mobile I'm not able to find the correct event.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After you have added the form to the DOM, use `.trigger('create');` on the form to initialize any widgets (form elements) you've just added:

```
...html('<form><input data-role="slider" type="text" /><input type="button" value="button" /></form>').trigger('create');
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TBRXk/