# How to reinitialize jQuery validation after changing the form?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, validation

I've got a form that is happily using jQuery validation.  I now need to modify the form to include a new form element that also requires validation.  Unfortunately, jQuery is dying during the (new) validation process, presumably because I've changed the form in ways that it doesn't understand.  Thus I suspect I need to reinitialize the validator on the new version of the form.

The question: How do I do this?  [Reinitialize jquery-mobile after inserting a form into the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733935/reinitialize-jquery-mobile-after-inserting-a-form-into-the-page) offered a promising suggestion of doing something like `$('#theform).trigger('create')`, but that didn't work for me.  Any advice out there?

Comment: What validation plugin are you using?

Comment: The "standard" bassistance.de plugin (v. 1.9.0).