# jQuery upon deleting single item from localstorage, others disappear from UI but still exist in localstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Okay so when I click delete on a record it seems to delete it from the Localstorage fine, but then when the page reloads none of the "drop downs" display the other records in localstorage even though they still exist?

Just wondering how I would go about fixing that.

```
// Variable Defaults
var aragStyles = ["1, 2 , 3 , 4"],
aragValue,
save = $("#submit"),
;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use your Developer Tools, you will see that the content is actually being loaded into the 'dropdowns'  ( I think they're officially called '[Collapsible Lists](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-collapsible.html)'  )  But I think that what's happening is that the lists aren't being properly 're-initialized' when they are being injected into the DOM.  Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733935/reinitialize-jquery-mobile-after-inserting-a-form-into-the-page) or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088837/jquery-mobile-triggercreate-command-not-working) for some help with

```
.trigger('create');
```

I looked at your code and I think you'll want that in your `getData()` function.  something like this:

```
$('#'+id+'items').append(elems);
```

becomes

```
$('#'+id+'items').append(elems).trigger('create');
```

Not sure I followed everything correctly, but it looks like that is where you are actually 'pushing' the Collapsible List to the browser.

EDIT:

To just update the whole page, you could do something like this:

```
$("div[data-role='content']").trigger("create").trigger( 'updatelayout' );
```

Comment: Yea that sounds like you'd be right.. but just adding  that didn't work  it actually seemed to add the collapsable lists into other collapsable lists and still not show the data that exists in local storage. But when I go back and go back into that same page the data just shows again like it did normal in the lists, hmm

Comment: hmm.  well, check out the [mobile docs about events](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)  scroll to the very bottom and check out the `updatelayout` section.  I've updated my answer as well.

Comment: That seemed to work somewhat, but when I am on the form page  for some reason the first time when I load the form page Display Data or th eback button in header cannot be clicked to #showall ... very odd but when i go back it can. Maybe I'm adding it to the wrong spot? I put it above the var elems =

Comment: and this is returned in console Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery18207078574332408607' of undefined jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js:2

Comment: Fixed some minor bugs, newest version is up

Comment: could you try changing your binding to the `pageinit` rather than the `pagecreate` in main.js line:25

`$('#distance').on("pageinit", function() {`

the reason is, I looked at the events docs here http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html and it says 
>"...because this will work regardless of whether the page is loaded directly or if the content is pulled into another page..."

Comment: Doing that gets rid of the Collapsable lists